# geomap and "country names"

Tags: api, google-maps

I would like to use a map API that allows me manipulating countries subregions like England and Scotland for instance (that are "provinces" of the United Kingdom, ISO-3166-1 code: GB).

All the APIs I've found so far only allow you to work on a ISO country basis (in which England and Scotland aren't accessible).

The Google geomap API documentation ([link](http://code.google.com/apis/visualization/documentation/gallery/geomap.html)) indicates that one can use "England" as a country name, however I've tested it and it doesn't work.

Does anybody know an API I could use to achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the ISO 3166-2 country subdivision code. For England this is `GB-ENG` or for Scotland `GB-SCT`. A complete lsit of codes can be found at http://docs.equest.com/eQuestCountryAndStateCodes.xls An example would be:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.google.com/jsapi'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages': ['geomap']});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawMap);

function drawMap() {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addRows(2);
  data.addColumn('string', 'Country');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Popularity');
  data.setValue(0, 0, 'GB-ENG');
  data.setValue(0, 1, 200);
  data.setValue(1, 0, 'GB-SCT');
  data.setValue(1, 1, 100);

  var options = {};
  options['dataMode'] = 'regions';
  options['region'] = 'GB';

  var container = document.getElementById('map_canvas');
  var geomap = new google.visualization.GeoMap(container);
  geomap.draw(data, options);
};
</script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id='map_canvas'></div>
</body>
```